# How do i disable copy paste menu in Error Text field when long press (magnifying glass comes up)

Tags: cosmicmind

func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        // Disable copy, select all, paste
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(*:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(*:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        // Default
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }